# .gif image not played after sometimes when switching from .png to .gif

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dealing with .gif image in HTML such that if I pressed switch then fan.gif is load and again press switch then fan.png image will load. It contains fan animation and I used .gif image to animate my fan. But after some few seconds my .gif is not working and stopped animating.

My HTML code is as follow:

```
<img id="foff" class="img-responsive ceiling-fan" src="img/foff.png" style=""/>
<img id="fon" class="img-responsive ceiling-fan" src="img/animatedfan1.gif" style="opacity:0;"/>
```

My jquery code is as follow :

```
$(function(){
var hit2 =0;
$('#tfanonoff').click(function(){
if  (hit2 % 2 !== 0)
                { //for hits 2,4,6,8
                $("#foff").animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
                $("#fon").animate({'opacity':'0'},1000);
                }
                else
                { // for hits 1,3,5,7   
                $("#foff").animate({'opacity':'0'},1000);
                $("#fon").animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

                }
               hit2++;
    return false;

});
});
```

My CSS is as follow:

```
.ceiling-fan{
    max-width: 20%; 
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    left: 41%;
    position: absolute; 
    transform: rotateX(-58deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting error(look in your console) because The Id's you are using in jquery are wrong. It is not `off` and `on` but `foff` and `fon`. intialize the value of  **hit1 to 1** so that it will show effect from first click itself. Try the below:

```js
$(function(){
var hit1 =1;
$('#aconoff').click(function(){
            if  (hit1 % 2 !== 0)
                {
                $("#foff").css({'opacity':'0'},1000);
                $("#fon").css({'opacity':'1'},1000);
                }
                else
                { // for hits 1,3,5,7
                $("#foff").css({'opacity':'1'},1000);
                $("#fon").css({'opacity':'0'},1000);
                }
               hit1++;
    return false;

});

});
```

```css
.ceiling-fan
{
max-width: 20%; 
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
left: 41%;
position: absolute; 
transform: rotateX(-58deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="foff" class="img-responsive ceiling-fan"  src="http://www.pngpix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Indoor-Ceiling-Fan-PNG-image.png" style=""/>
<img id="fon" class="img-responsive ceiling-fan" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/cTx9LHAGm5nd6/giphy.gif" style="opacity:0;"/>

<button id="aconoff">Switch</button>
```

Comment: @Maulik you are toggling the image then it should work run the snippet and see. is there any error ? see console.

Comment: my query is after sometimes my .gif file stop working..its not played at all.

Comment: bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:7(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:7(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:7

Comment: @Maulik it means you need to add tether.min.js before bootstrap .inclde this before bootstrap. visite here http://tether.io/ and get the file and add to your code.